# XML parsing: line 21, character 67, illegal qualified name character casting error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am using SQL Server 2014 and when I run below query I get this error message:

> XML parsing: line 21, character 67, illegal qualified name character

could this a casting error? My issue is that I dont know where is the problem is, I have read few questions regarding the similar issue, but still confused as to why this is happening can anyone please help me understand the error message.

Context: I have table called `tasks` that stores `p_num` (product number) and `descript` which stores notes of date and person updated the product order. I want to retrieve the date and person's name. However the issue is each p_num has multiple notes and all the notes are stored in single cell for each p_num and they are separated by space only. This approach seems to help me get my result, but I am getting this error message.

```
  Sample of text field(Descript):
   11/6/2018 2:04pm Standard pacific time - m.doe I need help with this issue & I might need help with this stupid issue 11/5/2018 1:05pm standard pacific time - m.doe I looked at the issue and I found it difficult to understand 11/4/2018 8:00am standard pacific time - j.moe issue has been registered
   end of all the note.
```

Output:

```
P_num    Date        Name
100      11/6/2018   m.doe
100      11/5/2018   m.doe
100      11/4/2018   j.moe
```

Code:

```
 DECLARE @tmp13 TABLE
                (
                   [p_Num] INTEGER NOT NULL,
                   [DESCRIPT] NVARCHAR(MAX)
                   PRIMARY KEY([p_Num])
                );

DECLARE @tmp13Parse TABLE
                    (
                        [Id] INT,
                        [Position] BIGINT,
                        [Value] NVARCHAR(500)
                        unique clustered ([Id], [Position])
                    );


 --insert test data
 INSERT INTO @tmp13 
  SELECT p_NUM,DESCRIPT FROM TASKS WHERE p_NUM >250000;



INSERT INTO @tmp13Parse (
                        [Id]
                      , [Position]
                      , [Value]
                    )
        SELECT      [a].[p_Num]
                  , [ss].[Position]
                  , [ss].[Value]
        FROM        @tmp13 [a]
        CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
 AS [Position]
                                  , [y].[i].[value]('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Value]
                        FROM        (
                                        SELECT [x] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'+ REPLACE([a].[DESCRIPT], ' ', '</i><i>')+ '</i>').[query]('.')
                                    ) AS [a]
                        CROSS APPLY [x].[nodes]('i') AS [y]([i])
                    ) AS [ss];



 SELECT      [a].[Id]
      , [a].[Value] AS [Date]
      , [ccc].[Value] AS [Name]
 FROM        @tmp13Parse [a]

 CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT MIN([aa].[Position]) + 1 AS [nameAnchorPosition]
            FROM   @tmp13Parse [aa]
            WHERE  [aa].[Id] = [a].[Id]
                   AND [aa].[Value] = '-'
                   AND [aa].[Position] > [a].[Position]
        ) AS [bb]

  CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT [cc].[Value]
            FROM   @tmp13Parse [cc]
            WHERE  [cc].[Id] = [a].[Id]
                   AND [cc].[Position] = [bb].[nameAnchorPosition]
                 )  AS [ccc]
   WHERE       TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [a].[Value]) > '1900-01-01';
```

Comment: We would need a sample of the XML to help you. There is no XML in your post.

Comment: I am not using any xml in the code. I am trying to convert to xml from text format. Descript column is a text field and I am trying to convert it into a xml format

Comment: okay I will edit the questions add the sample

Comment: If you're trying to convert your `(n)varchar` to `xml` then you have an `(v)varchar` that's in an xml format. If you don't, there is your problem. You can't put non-xml data into the `xml` datatype.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to convert nvarchar into xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be enough to change this

```
SELECT [x] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'+ REPLACE([a].[DESCRIPT], ' ', '</i><i>')+ '</i>')
```

to this

```
SELECT [x] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'+ REPLACE((SELECT [a].[DESCRIPT] AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')), ' ', '</i><i>')+ '</i>')
```

### Some explanation:

If you concatenate a string like `"this & that"` with tags you get something like

```
<SomeTag>this & that</SomeTag>
```

But this will fail, as the ampersand has to be escaped with `&amp;`. Luckily the implicit mechanisms will do all the escaping implicitly. Just try:

```
SELECT (SELECT 'See how &, < and > are escaped?' AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))
```

With this trick you can place strings with forbidden characters into XML:

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + (SELECT 'See how &, < and > are escaped?' AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')) + '</x>' AS XML);
```

The result

```
<x>See how &amp;, &lt; and &gt; are escaped?</x>
```